# building a Async Script in powershell

Tags: powershell, asynchronous

i am looking for a way to take a script that I have created. And simply run it against the individual printers all at once.  I do not care about returning any information other than success or failure if that is possible.

so far this is what I  have come up with:

```
$scriptBlock = {
                    param($PRINTSERVER,$PRINTER) 
                    . \\rictx-script-p2\Scripts\Module\OS\Print Server\Set-Permissions\Apply-PrinterPermissions3.ps1
                    Apply-PrinterPermissions -PrintServers $PRINTSERVER -PrinterName_Single $PRINTER
                }


$PSERVER = "MTHOH-PRINT-P06"
$MyPrinter = "WILPA0P30"
#Async
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList @($PSERVER,$MyPrinter)
```

The Script works great in parallel. But I am trying to speed up a 12 to 13 hour run on over 900 different printers in the environment. By applying the script async. The script is already configured to work on a print server as a whole and on a printer individually. To ensure there is a consistant permissions assigned to them all according to corporate policy.
On average the script takes about 1 to 1.5 minutes per printer to apply the printer ACL Changes.

My Thoughts was to have a script block load the printer permissions script, call the printers individually per job with the print server. And run about 50  to 100 jobs at once. This would require sending 2 paramaters to the script block for the function to be called.

What would be the best way to do this? Currently the script does nothing when I start the job. but works if I call the apply-printerpermissions3 script directly.

Other things I have tried:

```
$scriptBlock = {
                    param($P) 
                    . \\rictx-script-p2\Scripts\Module\OS\Print Server\Set-Permissions\Apply-PrinterPermissions3.ps1
                    Apply-PrinterPermissions -PrintServers $P[0] -PrinterName_Single $P[1]
                }


$PSERVER = "MTHOH-PRINT-P06"
$MyPrinter = "WILPA0P30"
#Async
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList @($PSERVER,$MyPrinter)

#Syncroneous
& $scriptBlock -PRINTSERVER $PServer -PRINTER $MyPrinter
```

The Sycroneous process works but the async does not.

Sorry I am not sure how to add my comment with code blocks as a reply:
I have tried this:

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName mthoh-print-p06
    $scriptBlock = { param($PRINTSERVER,$PRINTER)
                    Write-Host "$PRINTSERVER"
                    Write-Host "------------"
                    Write-Host "$Printer" 
                    . \\rictx-script-p2\Scripts\Module\OS\Print Server\Set-Permissions\Apply-PrinterPermissions3.ps1
                    Apply-PrinterPermissions -PrintServers $PRINTSERVER -PrinterName_Single $PRINTER }

$ArgumentList = "PSERVER", "Wilpa0p30"

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -AsJob -ArgumentList $ArgumentList



$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName mthoh-print-p06
$scriptBlock = { param($P)
                    Write-Host "$PRINTSERVER"
                    Write-Host "------------"
                    Write-Host "$Printer" 
                    . \\rictx-script-p2\Scripts\Module\OS\Print Server\Set-Permissions\Apply-PrinterPermissions3.ps1
                    Apply-PrinterPermissions -PrintServers $P[0] -PrinterName_Single $P[1] 
                }

$ArgumentList = "PSERVER", "Wilpa0p30"

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -AsJob -ArgumentList $ArgumentList
```

My Problem is this completes but does not appear to do anything. The script works if I call it locally just not working with Invoke-command.

I am not worried about the process of passing each printer name.  I can eaisly do:

```
foreach ( $Printer in ((Get-Printer -Computername $Server).Name) )
{do something to pass each command to my Printer ACL Script...}
```

My Printer ACL Script is configured to do a printer individually and process a server as a whole.

---

I think I have found something that works.  Thanks for your help:

```
$parameters = @{
    ComputerName = "mthoh-print-p06"
    ScriptBlock = { param($PRINTSERVER,$PRINTER)
                    
                    Write-host "$($env:COMPUTERNAME)  ---  $($env:USERNAME)"
                    Write-Host "$PRINTSERVER"
                    Write-Host "------------"
                    Write-Host "$Printer" 

                    $item = "\\rictx-script-p2\Scripts\Module\OS\Print Server\Set-Permissions\Apply-PrinterPermissions3.ps1"
                    ([System.IO.File]::Exists($Item))
                   
                    . "\\rictx-script-p2\Scripts\Module\OS\Print Server\Set-Permissions\Apply-PrinterPermissions3.ps1"
                    Apply-PrinterPermissions -PrintServers $PRINTSERVER -PrinterName_Single $PRINTER }
    ArgumentList = "mthoh-print-p06", "Wilpa0p30"
}
Invoke-Command @parameters -EnableNetworkAccess -AsJob
$j = Get-Job
$j | Format-List -Property *
$results = $j | Receive-Job
get-job | Where {$_state -ne "Running"} | Remove-Job
```

Comment: Why are you running a local job when you can run remote jobs on all servers in parallel with `Invoke-Command` ?

Comment: I am not opposed to it.  But I would like single sign on authenticaiton so I do not have to pass credientials.  Also I attempted to do this and it also failed for me:




$parameters = @{
    ComputerName = "Server01"
    ScriptBlock = { param($PRINTSERVER,$PRINTER) 
                    . \\rictx-script-p2\Scripts\Module\OS\Print Server\Set-Permissions\Apply-PrinterPermissions3.ps1
                    Apply-PrinterPermissions -PrintServers $PRINTSERVER -PrinterName_Single $PRINTER }
    ArgumentList = "PSERVER", "MyPrinter"
}
Invoke-Command @parameters -AsJob

Comment: I would like the ability to run async locally. But I am not against running the script remotely.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have 900 ps1 files with their own `$PServer='';$MyPrinter=''; & $ScriptBlock...`; the solution to your problem is going to rely on how you're managing the list of devices.

Comment: no I will be doing a querry into a array then foreach loop passing all the printers individually as a parameter to the Printer ACL Script.

Comment: Why don't you do something like `invoke-command server1,server2,server3 script.ps1 -args myarg1` where a local script will run in parallel on each server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in above comment. I'd try to run the scriptblock via `Invoke-Command` with the `-AsJob` parameter. Which will return a job, that you can await. Combined with PSRemoting you can fire multiple `Invoke-Command`s that'll return a job to a remote execution. See the [PowerShell docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1#example-8--run-a-background-job-on-several-remote-computers) for an example. If you need to pass local parameters to the remote job, in a readonly manner, see this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1#example-9--include-local-variables-in-a-command-run-on-a-remote-computer).

Comment: what both of these docu examples are missing is how to customize the run per server since each server has a different list of printers...

Comment: I like the option being offered but running into a road block.   My Problem is this completes but does not appear to do anything. The script works if I call it locally just not working with Invoke-command.

Comment: finally figured out that enablednetwork parameter needed to be added to the script.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not trying to cherry-pick the printers, it makes the task of standardizing the code across all the servers much simpler

```
$s = new-pssession -computername @(
   'MTHOH-PRINT-P05',
   'MTHOH-PRINT-P06'
)

$Init = get-content '\\rictx-script-p2\Scripts\Module\OS\Print Server\Set-Permissions\Apply-PrinterPermissions3.ps1' -raw
$RemoteJobs = invoke-command -session $s -scriptblock {
   $Init = [ScriptBlock]::Create($Using:Init)
   $MyName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
   
   $ServerJobs = foreach($MyPrinter in (get-printer -computername $MyName).name){
      start-job -InitializationScript $Init -ScriptBlock {
         param($PRINTSERVER,$PRINTER)
         Apply-PrinterPermissions -PrintServers $PRINTSERVER -PrinterName_Single $PRINTER
      } -ArgumentList $MyName,$MyPrinter
   }
   receive-job -job $ServerJobs -wait
   remove-job  -job $ServerJobs
} -AsJob

$null    = wait-job    -job $RemoteJobs
$results = receive-job -job $RemoteJobs
remove-job -job $RemoteJobs
```